# Popupwindow: ShowAsDropDown as top-right instead of bottom-left?

Tags: android, popupwindow

Is it possible to use `showAsDropDown` for `PopupWindows` and make them slide open in the top-right direction?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

yes it's possible. You can try this

```
mWindow.showAtLocation(mRootView, Gravity.TOP|Gravity.RIGHT, 0, distanceFromTop);
```

Comment: I am sorry but this doesnt slide open the window...and neither does it begin at the button, which opens it.

Comment: @BurninatorDor it will not open at the bottom it will open at top and right

Comment: @DjHacktorReborn In my case it is showing on top right of screen